# How to get a list of transactions related to an account?

Tags: transactions, accounts

I'm able to get transactions for an account by using the /history/get_actions rpc interface, but it seems to only list actions that were initiated by that account. It lists transfer actions, but only ones where the account was the sender.

How would I also get actions that where received by that account. For instance, I want to get actions for an account where the account was the receiver of a transfer.

Comment: any solution for the eos dev api or eosjs?

Comment: @Kabir
Are you sure the inline_keys data also contain the incoming transactions? The only incoming transaction I could find so far was from 'eosio.stake', memo: 'unstake', account: 'eosio.token', name: 'transfer'. btw found it in eosjs it's eos.getActions(account_name, (error, info) => {...})

Comment: @ismyhc: Did you found any solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `cleos` and getting json feed for actions on a given account, look a the inline_traces key. It should include all things and unfortunately sometimes duplicates. I had a lot of headaches cleaning up the inline_keys data for an EOS analytics project.

Comment: Link to the project? :)

Comment: How can I do the same with `eosjs` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
cleos -u http://eu1.eosdac.io get actions aaaaaaaaaaaa
```